# Where do variables declared in an IIFE go?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I understand the purpose of an IIFE is to take them out of the global scope. In the Angular style [guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), it says to avoid this:

```
/* avoid */
// logger.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('logger', logger);

// logger function is added as a global variable
function logger() { }

// storage.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('storage', storage);

// storage function is added as a global variable
function storage() { }
```

and instead do this:

```
/**
* recommended
*
* no globals are left behind
*/

// logger.js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('logger', logger);

    function logger() { }
})();

// storage.js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('storage', storage);

    function storage() { }
})();
```

I'm assuming this makes the storage function available for me to call in a controller some time later... but where exactly is it if it's not in the global scope?

Comment: Never used angular but the API wording suggests you've bound `storage` as a factory to `angular` or some kind of object referred to as `app` and potentially made it accessible with the alias `'storage'`.

Comment: @Marty Hmm... I think that makes sense. In that case it will give the factory access to the storage function but nothing else right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of IIFE Immediately Invoked Function Expression is to modularize your code creating isolated execution scopes. Angular has a Dependency Injection  system where the specified elements (factory, service, controller, directive, etc..) are registered and can be used through injection regardless their location. This is provided yo you by the angular FW. Angular has implicit and explicit injection;

The implicit injection uses the functions parameter names to automatically detect  the dependencies to inject. this is good for development but will break minified ugglified code. Good news there are tools that can convert your explicit injection into explicit i.e ng-anotate. your implicit injection code would look like

```
  // storage.js
(function() {
  'use strict';

   angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('storage',storage);

   function storage(logger) {
     // use logger
   }
})();
```

the explicit mode is where you actually provide the list of parameters that are to be passed through and array by their registered name and then match them with the function arguments. your code would look like this with explicit injection

```
// storage.js
(function() {
  'use strict';

   angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('storage', ['logger',storage]);

   function storage(logger) {
     // use logger
   }
})();
```

or

```
  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('storage', storage);
   storage.$inject = ['logger'];

   function storage(logger) {
     // use logger
   }
```

i hope this helps

Comment: so are you saying later I can inject storage implictly/explicitly? I guess I was asking where the storage function was stored, but Marty's comment helped me understand that, and your answer is a very informative extension!

Comment: the storage function is referenced by the angular's DI system. where it lives is not imporant what is important is that you can reference it from anywhere in the angular code if you inject it or if you requested through your applications $injector